# Social network htaccess redirect

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect

I'm building a php/mysql website and am facing a little problem, I have profiles in my website whereby a random user profile would have the following example link: www.MyDomain.com/profile.php?username=abc

What i would like to do, is show something like this in the address bar: www.MyDomain.com/abc

Also, if someone types in: www.MyDomain.com/abc, it should take him to "abc"'s profile which in reality is www.MyDomain.com/profile.php?username=abc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% how to do it with the root / level, but I think this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

There's a [real neat site](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) you can use to check your rules.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is mod rewrite.
There are a couple of decent generators out there. Have a play with them:

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

http://www.myseotool.com/free-seo-tools/htaccess-url-rewrite-generator.php

http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mod_rewrite-rewriterule-generator.shtml